# Qt Python radiobutton: activate event

Tags: python, user-interface, qt, qt4, pyqt

I am developing a project for one customer, where the design has a radio button with exclusive options.

Here is a piece of the code that runs and show two nice radio buttons:

```
    self.performGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.performGroupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 20, 181, 121))
    self.performGroupBox.setObjectName("performGroupBox")     

    self.consultRadioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.performGroupBox)
    self.consultRadioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 84, 18))
    self.consultRadioButton.setObjectName("consultRadioButton")

    self.insertRadioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.performGroupBox)
    self.insertRadioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 84, 18))
    self.insertRadioButton.setObjectName("insertRadioButton")
```

it just looks like:

```
perform:
    () Consult
    () Insert
```

The point here is, how to know what choice was marked: "consultRadioButton" or "insertRadioButton"?

Here is a sample on trying to get this information:

```
    if self.consultRadioButton.isChecked():
        self.call_Consult()
    if self.insertRadioButton.isChecked():
        self.call_Insert()
```

But it didn't do anything when the radiobutton is chosen.

Otherwise, using connect should be another option:

```
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.consultRadioButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(QString)"), self.call_Consult)  
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.insertRadioButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(QString)"), self.call_Insert)
```

But it didn't work either.

What is missing here... Any suggestion?

All comments are highly welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this signal instead:

```
void toggled (bool)
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggle

And example usage:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qradiobutton_widget.htm

Comment: The link is dead now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution... now working:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.radioButton1,QtCore.SIGNAL("toggled(bool)"),self.radio_activateInput)
```

when have the parameter bool included into toggled to signal, it worked.

Comment: piobyz gave you the name of the right signal — and then you re-answered yourself and denied him the big green check mark? Cold, man. That's cold.

Comment: @Brandon Rhodes - The answer by piobyz wasn't complete, as it only mentioned toggled(bool). But thanks for calling my attention, thus I just gave him the big green check mark, as you can check here - if there is anything else you mind, just let me know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753939/qt-python-radiobutton-activate-event

Comment: No, there is not anything else that I mind! And thank you for providing this extra information, showing how @piobyz’s answer looks when put into the `connect()` call. Thanks for giving him credit, and good luck in your future work on Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at QButtonGroup class

Answer (score 0):

```
# Assuming 'self' is a QtGui object
self.consultRadioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton('Consult')
# I prefer layout managers, but that is another topic
self.consultRadioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 84, 18))
self.consultRadioButton.setObjectName("consultRadioButton")

self.insertRadioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton('Insert')
self.insertRadioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 84, 18))
self.insertRadioButton.setObjectName("insertRadioButton")

# Set Default
self.consultRadioButton.setChecked(True)

# Create a Group and make it exclusive
self.methodGrp.setExclusive(True)

# Add radio buttons to group
self.methodGrp.addButton(self.consultRadioButton)
self.methodGrp.addButton(self.insertRadioButton)

# Connect Event handlers
self.consultRadioButton.clicked.connect(self.callConsult)
self.insertRadioButton.clicked.connect(self.callInsert)
```